# How can I get data with python socketio?

Tags: python, c#, socket.io

My Code:

```
import asyncio
import socketio

sio = socketio.Client()




@sio.event
def connect():
    print("I'm connected!")
    sio.emit('price_changed')



@sio.event
def connect_error(data):
    print("The connection failed!")

@sio.event
def disconnect():
    print("I'm disconnected!")


print('my sid is', sio.sid)



@sio.on('price_changed')
def on_message(data):
    sio.emit(data)
    print(data)

    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sio.connect('wss://www.haremaltin.com:2088')
    sio.wait()
```

When I run python, I get output like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lea5j.png)

The data I get is gold, euro, usd data.

I need want to assign each price to separate variable. Example:

USD = USDprice

EUR = EURprice

How can i assign each price to separate variable?

Comment: The response is json and you need to use a json parser/deserializer to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting JSON data back as a response. You're going to want to look into using the `json` library in order to parse it, and then get what you will from it. When you parse it, it'll come in as a `dict` so you just have to navigate that dictionary to pull the values out that you want.